# sql query greater than DATE (year) A but less than DATE (year) B

Tags: mysql

I have a list of items like so:

```
Field: Name & Field: DOB
- David - 1962
- Robert - 1955
- Tracy - 1980
- Bono - 1964
- Betty - 1968
```

I need a simple SQL query that will return all name whose birth years ate in the 1960s (1960-1969). something along the lines of this logic:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DOB => '1960' AND DOB =< '1969' AND ORDER BY name";
```

FYI: Currently the DOB field in the employee database is a VARCHAR field with 4 character designation.

Can someone point me to the correct syntax on such a query?

Comment: it should be `<=` and not `=<`

Comment: use $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DOB >= '1960' AND DOB <= '1969' AND ORDER BY name";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* be storing date/time information as `varchar`, but since you have one way you can screen for 1960s birthdays is to just check the first three characters of the `DOB` field:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE SUBSTRING(DOB, 1, 3) = '196'
ORDER BY name
```

You could also use your original approach, with the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE DOB >= '1960' AND DOB <= '1969'
```

However, I don't like treating strings as numbers, because you get weird things happening if the strings should ever change length.  I would advise you to use a `datetime` to store your `DOB` information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query from:

```
"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DOB => '1960' AND DOB =< '1969' AND ORDER BY name";
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DOB >= '1960' AND DOB <= '1969' AND ORDER BY name";
// Its >= or <= not => or =<
```

and try again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your varchar DOB column contains only numbers:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
WHERE CONVERT(DOB, INTEGER) >= 1960
   AND CONVERT(DOB, INTEGER) <= 1969
```

Answer (score 0):

Did You try this ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE DOB Like '%YYY%'AND ORDER BY name";
```

Consider yyy is 196X so all dob starting with 196 will result.

But this can't be specific enough

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tt1 where year >='1960' and year <='1969' order by name
```

Hope this will help.